# Command Not Handled Exception

Tags: xpages

I'm new to Domino Designer.  I'm trying to modify an existing application which is running on a remote server.  I create a blank xPage and view in browser and it works.  I add a label and view in browser and it works.  I add a combo box and setup a data source for my xPage.  The data source is in the current application and I'm using a view.  I setup my combo to point to that data source and specify BindTo value.  I view it in browser and I get Error 500  "HTTP Web Server:  Command Not Handled Exception"  I can open the view that I've used and see all the data in the view.  I can even add, edit, and delete from the view.

Ideas... Thnxs in advance.

Additional Info.  I've added a "View" from "Container Controls" and used the same data source and the same view and it also works in the browser.

The error being printed is:

```
    javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Error getting property 'CompanyName' from bean of type lotus.domino.local.View 
com.sun.faces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getValue(PropertyResolverImpl.java:119) 
com.ibm.xsp.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getValue(PropertyResolverImpl.java:144) 
com.sun.faces.el.impl.ArraySuffix.evaluate(ArraySuffix.java:182) 
com.sun.faces.el.impl.ComplexValue.evaluate(ComplexValue.java:163) 
com.sun.faces.el.impl.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.j‌​ava:257)
com.sun.faces.el.ValueBindingImpl.getValue(ValueBindingImpl.java:150) ....
```

Comment: Are you specifying values that can be included in the combobox? How are you doing that if you are. Could you please include some XML and or code?

Comment: Could you show us the source code for the xpage, at leset the <xp:data> and the <xp:combobox> tags

Comment: First step here is to enable the "default error page" to display the real stack trace of the error. You can set it up in the application/xsp properties of your database (app properties = 8.5.3, xsp properties = 9.0+). Then you can post the stack trace in full to us.

Comment: Also, use XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF for easy access to the XPages log files. You need that in order to see what the actual error is. Let us know what it is and we can help you.

Comment: javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Error getting property 'CompanyName' from bean of type lotus.domino.local.View
    com.sun.faces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getValue(PropertyResolverImpl.java:119)
    com.ibm.xsp.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getValue(PropertyResolverImpl.java:144)
    com.sun.faces.el.impl.ArraySuffix.evaluate(ArraySuffix.java:182)
    com.sun.faces.el.impl.ComplexValue.evaluate(ComplexValue.java:163)
    com.sun.faces.el.impl.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.evaluate(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:257)
    com.sun.faces.el.ValueBindingImpl.getValue(ValueBindingImpl.java:150)  ....

Comment: Up until now, I have only bound comboboxes to document data sources and have not tried to bind them to views.  My first question would be whether or not this is possible, second if you selected that the view can have its data changed directly in the view.  In either case, I suggest you use a repeater and an inline form to do the changes that way.  The ExtLib demo database has a great example for something like that and it looks great.

Comment: That was it.  I changed my data source to a document and it fixed the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was already answered in the comments, but I want to write a better answer.

The problem in this case is that a view data source is being used for editing a document.  Directly, this is not a possibility, though there are a few great ways to get around this.  The first way, and my favorite, is to use an inline form.  I think the Extension Library Demo database offers a few great examples of how to go about doing this.  One way is to use a tooltip dialog.  Another way is an inline form.  A repeater is used and for every row in the view, a hidden panel can be made which contains the document data source and all field which are required to be changeable.  By clicking on a button or link, the panel is made visible.  This is my favorite variant because it is simple, quick, and generally looks great.

Another way to go about this is to have a view data source only, but use scripts to retrieve the document and set the values in the background and then save and release.  It all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

My main recommendation is to look at the ExtLib demo and take a look at what they are doing there.

Comment: I think it was just my misunderstanding of how to use a combo box that I was trying to bind it to a view because I thought that the binding was the values that appear in the drop-down when you drop it down.  Now that I've poked around a bit that is under the "values" tab.  What is bind to is the selectedvalue.  So binding to the document is just what I needed.  sorry....REALLY new to xPages and Lotus Notes :)